# Bugged Splashscreen, can't access Code to fix it

Tags: vba, excel

I added a Splashscreen to my Excel file and added code to hide the border and upper bar. This means no OK button or X to close the Splashscreen. I did not think about that and now I can't open the excel file, as it is stuck on the Splash Screen and I can't open the VBA code by pressing Alt+F11. Opening the file in Safe Mode doesn't seem to help.

Any Advice? I do have a backup file without the splashscreen, but it's a rather ancient one without some added features that I added today, so I'd like to make the one with the splashscreen bug usable again.

Comment: Simply disallow all VBA execution.on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to fix this brainfart myself. Turns out you can't close Excel or the Splashscreen, but you can Alt+F4, which closes the Splashscreen and not Excel. Weird reaction but it fixes my Problem!

Comment: The Splashscreen is just a window, which unless you set ShowModal to false will maintain focus until closed. Hitting Alt-F4 is just the equivalent of hitting your hidden Close Window (X) button. Create an `Application.OnTime` event to close it, or make the window close on click..?

Comment: I had a similar problem once and ended up adding a button to screen to turn menus back on.  I found it very useful for myself, especially for debugging, and eventually just left it in the finished project, in case the user prefers it.